# Spring-integration SpEL: Logging pass Message as a parameter to the method

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-el

Can I pass Message as a parameter to the method in SpEL rather than headers or payload:

```
    <logging-channel-adapter id="logger" channel="outputLoggingChannel" level="INFO" expression="T(xxx.XmlUtils).prettyPrint(message)" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing **#root** as a parameter we can pass the whole Message including headers and payload.

```
    <logging-channel-adapter id="logger" channel="outputLoggingChannel" level="INFO" expression="T(xxx.XmlUtils).prettyPrint(#root)" />
```